# ASP.NET Core 1.1 targeting full framework can not be deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I used the ASP.NETCore 1.0.1 Web App template and attempted to upgrade it ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 using full framework. The app runs fine when run locally, but when I attempt to deploy it to Azure I receive the following (See image below). The project.json changes are included as well below. Are full framework version of 1.1 supported in Azure yet? Is there any workaround to getting this type of app working?

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServicesIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're deploying via WebDeploy (e.g. from VS) or via git?

Comment: This probably won't fix your issue, but FYI: the ASP.NET tools have been updated from `1.0.0-preview2-final` to `1.1.0-preview4-final`.

Comment: What happens if you set "runtimes": { "win7-x64": {} } in project.json?

Comment: You are mixing package versions. You also need to show the exact error you get otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: That might not be the problem here but remove your package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` from the `dependencies` section. It should be only under `tools`

Comment: It can be repro at first time I used your project. json file . Then I created another .net core project and try to deploy the WebApp on the azure. First time change  `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc":  from “1.0.0” to"1.1.0"` , it works well on the Azure portal, and then replace the content with your project.json file totally. It still work correctly. But I can’t repro the issue any more even with new project . So could you please have a try to create a new WebApp and redeploy it again?

Comment: I'm using the publish operation from VS, so WebDeploy.

Comment: I tried to upgrade the tools, but it says this package is not supported in using .NET 4.6. Errors in C:\Users\steve\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestASP.NETCore1-1\src\TestASP.NETCore1-1\TestASP.NETCore1-1.xproj
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final is not compatible with net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.

Comment: I attempted to look through the logs on Azure, but I'm not seeing any errors. It seems like the app is not able to start which why there is no logging. The browser just receives a 500 and displays the image from above. Is there somewhere else I can look to see why the app hasn't started?

Comment: I tried adding the "runtimes" section, but this didn't help. I also moved all the tools based packages back into the tools section. It appears the NuGet package manager isn't smart enough to know what section they should be placed in. However, this didn't help as you seemed to indicate. Upgrading just the MVC library doesn't work because Routing package is still on 1.0.1. You get a compile time error, so I'm not sure exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 11/28/16 this problem appears to be gone. My assumption is this was Azure issue. This issue was also filed on the ASP.NET Core repo here: [ASP.NET Core 1.1 targeting full framework can not be deployed to Azure App Service](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1839)